# Statistics question on basil bush random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification

The height, $H$, in meters of a basil bush is a random variable with the probability density function $f_{_H}(t)=e^t,\;0\leq t\leq H_0$ such that $H_0$ is the maximal height.

> $\color{blue}{(1)}$ I need to find $H_0$
>
> $\color{blue}{(2)}$ to find the average height of the basil bush
>
> $\color{blue}{(3)}$ to find the probability that the height of the basil bush is at least $0.3$ meters, exactly $0.3$ meters, at the most $0.3$ meters
>
> $\color{blue}{(4)}$ A basil bush is considered adult if its height is at least $0.3$ meters.
> What is the probability that the height of the adult basil bush is bigger then $0.5$ meters? Bigger then $(0.7)$ meters?

My attempt:

$\color{blue}{(1)}$
$$1=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{_X}(t)dt=\int_{0}^{H_0}e^t(t)dt=e^{H_0}-1$$

$$e^{H_0}=2, \;H_0=\ln(2)\approx\boxed{0.693}$$

$\color{blue}{(2)}$

$$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}t\cdot f_{_X}(t)dt=\int_{0}^{\ln(2)}t\cdot e^t(t)dt$$

$\color{gray}{\text{By parts z=t dz=dt  , dg=$e^tdt$, $g=e^t$}}$
$$$$

$$te^t\bigg|_{0}^{\ln(2)}-\int_{0}^{\ln(2)} e^tdt=\ln(2)e^{\ln(2)}-2+1\approx\boxed{0.386}$$

$\Longrightarrow$

The average height is 0.386 meters

$\color{blue}{(3)}$

At least $0.3:$

$P(X\leq 0.3)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{0.3}e^tdt \approx \boxed{0.349}$

Exactly $0.3:$

$P(X=0.3)=\boxed{0}$

At the most $0.3:$

$P(X \geq 0.3)=1-0.349\approx \boxed{0.651}$

$\color{blue}{(4)}$

$P(X> 0.5)=\displaystyle\int_{0.5}^{\ln(2)}=0.351\;,P(X\geq 0.3)=0.651,\;P(0.3\times 0.5)=P(0.15)=0.161$

$P(X\geq 0.5\big|X\geq 0.3)=\boxed{\frac{0.161}{0.351}}$

$P(X>0.7)=\displaystyle\int_{0.7}^{\ln(2)}e^tdt=2-e^{0.7}\approx 0.0138$

$P(X> 0.7\big|X\geq 0.3)=\frac{}{0.351}$

> Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About part (4), you have $P (   X \ge 0.5  \mid X \ge 0.3) = \frac{ P( X \ge 0.5 \textrm{ and } X \ge 0.3)}{ P( X \ge 0.3) }$. And $ P( X \ge 0.5 \textrm{ and } X \ge 0.3) \neq P( X \ge 0.15)$. So you must divide by $P( X \ge 0.3)$ instead of $P(X \ge 0.5)$. And we have $P(X \ge 0.5 \textrm{ and } X \ge 0.3) = P(X \ge 0.5)$ as $X \ge 0.5$ already implies $X \ge 0.3$.

Comment: I suppose you know from conditional probability $P(A \mid B ) = \frac{ P ( A \cup B ) }{P(B)}$, we know have $A = X \ge 0.7$ and $B= X \ge 0.3$.

Comment: $P(X>0.7)=\displaystyle\int_{0.7}^{\ln(2)}e^tdt$?

Answer (score 0):

After using @Hetebrij answer

$\color{blue}{(4)}$

$P(X> 0.5)=\displaystyle\int_{0.5}^{\ln(2)}=0.351\;,P(X\geq 0.3)=0.651$

$P(X\geq 0.5\big|X\geq 0.3)=\boxed{\frac{0.351}{0.651}\approx 0.539}$

---

$P(X>0.7)=\boxed0$ because that the max height is $\ln(2)\approx 0.69$